# $ is not definedエラーの解決方法

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

javascript内の　var name = $("#in").val();　の部分で、
$ is not definedになってしまいます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="createUrl.js"></script>
<span>
    入力欄
    <input type="text" id="in">
    <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="x()">
    <br>
    <br>
</span>

<span>
    表示欄
    <input type="text" id="out" size="100">
</span>
</body>
</html>

*javascript 
// okボタン押下時イベント
function x() {
// id=inのテキストボックス取得
var name = $("#in").val();
// ホスト名取得
var localhost = window.location.host;
// 取得した入力を基に、URL作成
var url = "http://fujimicwapi.azurewebsites.net/api/MstUsers";
// 表示欄にjsonのデータを出力
$.get(url, { serchStr: name }, function (data) {
    $("#out").val(JSON.stringify(data));
});
}
```

解決方法が分かりません。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$はJQueryのobjectです。
JQueryを読み込んであげないと定義されません。
JQueryを読み込んであげましょう。

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

とりあえず、以下のどちらかを追加すれば、そのエラーはなくなります。

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決することが出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

jquery.jsが読み込まれていないように見受けられます。